# How do I view what enemy is holding in openxcom?

Tags: open-xcom

I have been watching the Yogscast's openxcom series for some time and I have noticed that they press a button while playing *The XCOM files* modpack that allows them to view what enemies are holding in their hands and if they are wounded. While looking through the settings of openxcom, I cannot find the button that shows these stats. For example:
[image]

**What is the button for this in openxcom or is this an additional mod/feature for *The XCOM files*?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Middle-mouse-click** on the unit.

This is an additional feature of [OpenXcom Extended](https://openxcom.org/forum/index.php/topic,5251.0.html) (used by mods like X-Com Files and X-Piratez).

Comment: What if my middle mouse click doesn't work?

Comment: @Boolean Make sure you don't have scrolling assigned to MMB as well.

Answer (score 0):

It's a feature of OpenXcom, but only works on mindcontrolled, non terrorist aliens.

[Here's a list of all differences between the Xcom and openXcom](https://www.ufopaedia.org/index.php/Differences_to_X-COM_(OpenXcom)). The inventory view is mentioned in the "Battlescape" section.